# Analysis with CMB Data

Tags: resource-recommendations, cosmic-microwave-background, data

I have read about Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation from Weinberg's Cosmology Book. I'm looking forward for specific resources to analyse real time CMB Data recorded by Physicists. Any papers, notes or textbooks are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The data of the Planck mission are open, you can find them at

https://pla.esac.esa.int/#home

The data analysis of Plank from the raw data is pretty complicated, as you have to subtract know effects (such as the rotation of the galaxy, calibration of the instrument and so on) before reaching the high level data, which then are used to compute the CMB power spectrum.

Comment: any resources for converting this raw data to high level data?